# Validação campo numérico PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function valida_valor2($str)
{
    $count = strlen($str);

    if (($count > 19) OR (!is_numeric($str))) {
        return "INVALIDO";
    }else {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Quando chamo ela no meu codigo retorna `INVALIDO` nessa seguinte chamada: Sendo que as variáveis `$valor_iem9... = 0;`

```
if ((valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_a) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_b) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_c) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_d) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_e) == 'INVALIDO')) {
    echo "Campo IEM9 Pessoa Física inválido";
    exit;
}
```

Alguma luz?

Comment: Tente usar `AND` ao invés de `OR`, para verificar se as duas condições são satisfeitas.

Comment: Você quer validar somente dígitos nada ponto ou traço certo?

Comment: Isso. quero entrar com digitos.

Comment: A função em si eu acredito estar certa mas estou com problemas na hora que chamo.

Comment: Na verdade quando você passa o '0' pela função ele não interpreta como um 'int', converta o valor para string antes de utilizar na função.

Answer (score 1):

Para validar se entrada (string) contêm somente dígitos use a função `ctype_digit()`.

Pode simplificar a lógica juntando essas variáveis em um array e então aplicar a função `valida_valor2()` para cada elemento com `array_filter()` no callback faça a comparação se o valor retornado é INVALIDO.

Por último verifique se a soma dos elementos inválidos é maior ou igual a um.

```
function valida_valor2($str){
    $count = strlen($str);

    if (!ctype_digit("$str") || $count > 19) {
        return "INVALIDO";
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

//junta as variáveis em um array
$arr = array(
    $iem9_f_a = str_repeat(1, 5),
    $iem9_f_b = str_repeat(2, 19),
    $iem9_f_c = str_repeat(2, 19),
    $iem9_f_d = '123abc',
    $iem9_f_e =  1.99
);


$validacao = array_filter($arr, function($item){ return valida_valor2($item) == 'INVALIDO';});


if(array_sum($validacao)){
    echo 'existem erros <pre>';
    print_r($validacao);
}else{
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: o erro persiste.

Acredito que meu problema esteja aqui: if ((valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_a) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_b) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_c) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_d) == 'INVALIDO') || (valida_valor2($valor_iem9_f_e) == 'INVALIDO')) {
    echo "Campo IEM9 Pessoa Física inválido";
    exit;
}

Comment: @olifreitas o problema é no if e não na função

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo assim:

```
function valida_valor2($str)
{
    $count = strlen($str);

    if (($count > 19) OR (!is_numeric($str))) {
        return "INVALIDO";
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

if ((valida_valor2(strval($valor_iem9_f_a)) == 'INVALIDO')) {
    echo "Campo IEM9 Pessoa Física inválido";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: mas eu poderia agrupar varias variáveis nesse if? pois tenho valor_iem9_f_a, valor_iem9_f_b, valor_iem9_f_c, valor_iem9_f_d

Comment: Sim, da mesma for que você fez, apenas usado o `strval()` em cada valor recebido

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver dessa forma?

Comment: Ainda continua retornando INVALIDO.

if ((valida_valor2(strval($valor_iem9_f_a)) == 'INVALIDO') OR (valida_valor2(strval($valor_iem9_f_b)) == 'INVALIDO') OR (valida_valor2(strval($valor_iem9_f_c)) == 'INVALIDO') OR (valida_valor2(strval($valor_iem9_f_d)) == 'INVALIDO') OR (valida_valor2(strval($valor_iem9_f_e)) == 'INVALIDO')) {
    echo "Campo IEM9 Pessoa Física inválido";
    exit;
}